# Are job IDs unique across backends?

Tags: programming, qiskit

Are job IDs unique across backends, or is it possible that two jobs on two different backends have the same job ID? I'd like to use the job ID as primary key in a database.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are unique across the full system. They are assigned by the server and it is safe to use them as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience if you are running the jobs with the same login, but on different machines they would still have unique IDs even on the backend. I am not sure about different logins and different machines though.

*the top 3 were ran on my laptop, all the bottom ones were ran on my PC*
[image]